# RestSharp posting Client Secret to Api

Tags: restsharp

I am replacing WebClient from RestSharper to call the Rest client.
Below is the working code from WebClient but the same code is not working from RestClient

WebClient:

```
   using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var reqparm =
                    new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
                    {
                        {"client_id", _configurationTickle.ClientId},
                        {"client_secret", _configurationTickle.ClientSecret},
                        {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
                        {"code", authCode},
                        {"redirect_uri", _configurationTickle.CallBackUrl}
                    };

                byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);
                string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
            }
```

RestSharp:

```
var client1 = new RestClient(_configurationTickle.BaseUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(_configurationTickle.TokenRequestEndPoint,Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("client_id", _configurationTickle.ClientId);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", _configurationTickle.ClientSecret);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        request.AddParameter("code", authCode);
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", _configurationTickle.CallBackUrl);
        IRestResponse response = client1.Execute(request);
```

Can you please help whats wrong with the request in RestSharp, I am getting Invalid request error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`urlencoded` type request should be given as below and please check with the below modified code

```
 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Key1=value1&Key2=value2&....", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

**Modified Code:**

```
var client1 = new RestClient(_configurationTickle.BaseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(_configurationTickle.TokenRequestEndPoint,Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


String body="client_id="+_configurationTickle.ClientId+"&client_secret="+_configurationTickle.ClientSecret+"&grant_type=authorization_code&code="+authCode+"&redirect_uri="_configurationTickle.CallBackUrl;

request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```